# Seeing custom Tag Manager keys in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-sdk

This [youtube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Bx8BU3wxaA&t=202s) inclues a `page_path` event key.  I tried including the same thing in this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ga-test?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts):

```
  uaClick1() {
    console.log("CLICKED UA 1")
    gtag('event', 'MY_BUTTON_1_CLICK', {
      'page_path': "in",
      'event_category': 'BUTTON_CLICK',
      'event_label': 'UA Click 1',
      'value': 'Some custom value 1'   })
  }
```

However I don't see the custom key showing up in Google Analytics:

[image]

Is it possible to add custom keys as shown?  Also IIUC the `value` key is standard, but I don't see that either.  Is there some other place I should be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you can't pass custom data in that way. first, you'll need to set up custom dimension/metrics and then use specific mappings as shown in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets):

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'event_label'}
});

//...

gtag('event', 'MY_BUTTON_1_CLICK', {
    'page_path': "in",
    'event_category': 'BUTTON_CLICK',
    'event_label': 'UA Click 1',
    'value': 334   }) // has to be numerical value
```